# Trying to do a hover effect on two different words in a header

Tags: css

I'm brand new here, so please go easy on me cause I'm learning. Basically I have a header that has some text in it as shown here:

```
<section id="hero">
<header><span id="first">Dwayne <> </span><span id="last">Rill Jr.</span></header>
<hr>
<p>Aspiring Designer & Developer</p>
<button id="cta-works">Take a look at my work</button>
</section>
```

I want to make a hover effect that works on both the first and last name, and in effect switches the colors between the two elements (the first name color is white and turns teal, the second name color is teal and turns white).

```
#hero  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #0b0c10;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 200;
  cursor: default;
}

#first {
  color: #66fcf1;
}

#first:hover {
  color: white;
}

#last {
  color: white;
}

#last:hover {
  color: #66fcf1;
}
```

I tried using two separate spans to get it to work, but it only changes the color when I scroll over "first" but not "second". I want to get it to where when you roll over either side of the header it flips the colors. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the hover to `header` instead:

```css
#hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #0b0c10;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 200;
  cursor: default;
}

#first {
  color: #66fcf1;
}

header:hover #first {
  color: white;
}

#last {
  color: white;
}

header:hover #last {
  color: #66fcf1;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <header><span id="first">Dwayne </span><span id="last">Rill Jr.</span></header>
  <hr>
  <p>Aspiring Designer & Developer</p>
  <button id="cta-works">Take a look at my work</button>
</section>
```

The reason you can't use this with the span elements is that you'd have to use the sibling selector (`#first:hover ~ #last`), but this only selects siblings *after* an element, so you couldn't select `#first` with `#last` (`#last:hover ~ #first`).

Comment: Ahhh! I was thinking it would be something like that (with using header and the span tag on the same attribute), just didn't quite know how to do it. Thanks so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the hover effect is on the individual text elements. If you put the hover effect on the header then any time the user hovers over anything in the header the text colors will change.

Example:

```css
header:hover #first {
  color: white;
}
```

In the example the header gets the hover selector and then the color change happens to the element with the id of "first" if it is inside the header.

Full example:

```css
#hero  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #0b0c10;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 200;
  cursor: default;
}

#first {
  color: #66fcf1;
}

#last {
  color: white;
}

header:hover #first {
  color: white;
}

header:hover #last {
  color: #66fcf1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with Javascript -

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("mouseover", function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("first").style.color = "teal";
    document.getElementById("last").style.color = "white";
  });
  document.getElementById("last").addEventListener("mouseover", function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("last").style.color = "teal";
    document.getElementById("first").style.color = "white";
  });
  document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("mouseout", function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("first").style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById("last").style.color = "teal";
  });
  document.getElementById("last").addEventListener("mouseout", function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("last").style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById("first").style.color = "teal";
  });
</script>
```

Snippet-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #hero  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #0b0c10;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 200;
  cursor: default;
}

#first {
  color: #66fcf1;
}

#first:hover {
  color: white;
}

#last {
  color: white;
}

#last:hover {
  color: #66fcf1;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="hero">
    <header><span id="first">Dwayne &lsaquo; </span><span id="last">&rsaquo; Rill Jr.</span></header>
    <hr>
    <p>Aspiring Designer & Developer</p>
    <button id="cta-works">Take a look at my work</button>
    </section>

    <script>
      document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("mouseover", function mouseOver() {
        document.getElementById("first").style.color = "teal";
        document.getElementById("last").style.color = "white";
      });
      document.getElementById("last").addEventListener("mouseover", function mouseOver() {
        document.getElementById("last").style.color = "teal";
        document.getElementById("first").style.color = "white";
      });
      document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("mouseout", function mouseOut() {
        document.getElementById("first").style.color = "white";
        document.getElementById("last").style.color = "teal";
      });
      document.getElementById("last").addEventListener("mouseout", function mouseOut() {
        document.getElementById("last").style.color = "white";
        document.getElementById("first").style.color = "teal";
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```